# jq: Alternate between arguments seperated by the comma operator

Tags: json, jq

I have a `json` that's structured like:

```json
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Hello",
    "active": true,  
    "author": {
      "firstName": "Jane",
      "lastName": "Smith",    
      "email": "hello@example.com",
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "World",
    "active": true,  
    "author": {
      "firstName": "John",
      "lastName": "Doe",    
      "email": "world@example.com",
    }
  }
]
```

With `jq '.[].name, .[].author.email' foo.json`

I get the list of all names, and the list of all emails. However, they do not display in an alternating format, with one name following each email

I thought maybe it should output the parent array, and then pipe that into a new object like this:

`jq '.[] | {name: .[].name, email: .[].author.email}' foo.json`

However, that seems like it is a syntactically wrong approach.

What's the correct notation/syntax for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One iteration is what’s needed here:

```
.[] | (.name, .author.email)
```